# R convert binary data using random sample

Tags: r

**How to convert binary data**

```
1  0  1  1  0  0  0
0  1  0  1  0  1  1
1  1  1  0  1  0  1
```

**To data in this format:**

```
1 0.95  2 0.32  3 0.89  4 0.97  5 0.11  6 0.20 7 0.31
1 0.11  2 0.92  3 0.34  4 0.94  5 0.21  6 0.90 7 0.81
1 0.97  2 0.82  3 0.89  4 0.17  5 0.96  6 0.13 7 0.91
```

**such that:**
each value represented within two digit:

1- integer represents its position,and

2- float value is given randomly from `0.70 to 0.99` if the original value = one, and

from `0.10 to 0.39` if the original value =zero

I know how to generate random sample, i.e.

```
x <- 1:7
y <- sample(seq(0.70, 0.99,by=0.01),length(x),replace=FALSE)
```

But I don't know how to tell R if X==1 generate random sample values from `0.70 to 0.99` otherwise generate random sample values from `0.10 to 0.39`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `mm` be your sample input matrix

```
mm <- matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1), ncol=7)
```

You can generate the correct sequences of integers with

```
idx <- col(mm)
```

and you can generate your random number with `ifelse()`

```
val <- ifelse(mm==1, 
    runif(length(mm), .7, .99), 
    runif(length(mm), .1, .39))
```

technically we do generate some numbers we don't use but it's usually fast enough that's not a problem. Finally we can combine them with

```
matrix(rbind(idx, val), nrow=3)

#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5]  [,6] [,7]  [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
# [1,]    1 0.734    2 0.707    3 0.214    4 0.246    5 0.822     6 0.919     7 0.887
# [2,]    1 0.150    2 0.353    3 0.332    4 0.724    5 0.768     6 0.936     7 0.304
# [3,]    1 0.708    2 0.321    3 0.790    4 0.193    5 0.808     6 0.224     7 0.872
```

Comment: Similar: `val <- mm*runif(length(mm), .7, .99)+(1-mm)*runif(length(mm), .1, .39)` and `val <- mm; val[] <- runif(length(mm),ifelse(mm,.7,.1),ifelse(mm,.99,.39))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally choose the runif range with `ifelse`:

```
set.seed(144)
t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) rbind(seq(length(x)),
                                  ifelse(x == 1, runif(length(x), 0.7, 0.99),
                                         runif(length(x), 0.1, 0.39)))))
#      [,1]      [,2] [,3]      [,4] [,5]      [,6] [,7]      [,8] [,9]     [,10] [,11]
# [1,]    1 0.7143302    2 0.1225158    3 0.9107380    4 0.8452873    5 0.1519741     6
# [2,]    1 0.1081755    2 0.7156656    3 0.2653289    4 0.8529043    5 0.3622948     6
# [3,]    1 0.8798000    2 0.7516552    3 0.8467378    4 0.2338804    5 0.7888522     6
#          [,12] [,13]     [,14]
# [1,] 0.2599710     7 0.1423132
# [2,] 0.8107819     7 0.7807105
# [3,] 0.3009073     7 0.7231688
```

The `ifelse` statement chooses between the `runif` vectors drawn with the two different ranges, and the `rbind` interleaves the indices and random numbers.